# make 3d numpy array using for loop in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d, 2d

I have training data with 2 dimension. (200 results of 4 features)

I proved 100 different applications with 10 repetition resulting 1000 csv files.

I want to stack each csv results for machine learning.
But I don't know how.

each of my csv files look like below.

test1.csv to numpy array data

```
[[0 'crc32_pclmul' 445 0]
 [0 'crc32_pclmul' 270 4096]
 [0 'crc32_pclmul' 234 8192]
 ...
 [249 'intel_pmt' 272 4096]
 [249 'intel_pmt' 224 8192]
 [249 'intel_pmt' 268 12288]]
```

I tried below python code.

```
path = os.getcwd()
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
cnt=0
for f in csv_files:
    cnt +=1
    seperator = '_'
    app = os.path.basename(f).split(seperator, 1)[0]

    if cnt==1:
        a = np.array(preprocess(f))
        b = np.array(app)
    else:
        a = np.vstack((a, np.array(preprocess(f))))
        b = np.append(b,app)
print(a)
print(b)
```

preprocess function returns df.to_numpy results for each csv files.

My expectation was like below. a(1000, 200, 4)

```
[[[0 'crc32_pclmul' 445 0]
 [0 'crc32_pclmul' 270 4096]
 [0 'crc32_pclmul' 234 8192]
 ...
 [249 'intel_pmt' 272 4096]
 [249 'intel_pmt' 224 8192]
 [249 'intel_pmt' 268 12288]],
[[0 'crc32_pclmul' 445 0]
 [0 'crc32_pclmul' 270 4096]
 [0 'crc32_pclmul' 234 8192]
 ...
 [249 'intel_pmt' 272 4096]
 [249 'intel_pmt' 224 8192]
 [249 'intel_pmt' 268 12288]],
...
[[0 'crc32_pclmul' 445 0]
 [0 'crc32_pclmul' 270 4096]
 [0 'crc32_pclmul' 234 8192]
 ...
 [249 'intel_pmt' 272 4096]
 [249 'intel_pmt' 224 8192]
 [249 'intel_pmt' 268 12288]]]
```

However, I'm getting this. a(200000, 4)

```
[[0 'crc32_pclmul' 445 0]
 [0 'crc32_pclmul' 270 4096]
 [0 'crc32_pclmul' 234 8192]
 ...
 [249 'intel_pmt' 272 4096]
 [249 'intel_pmt' 224 8192]
 [249 'intel_pmt' 268 12288]]
```

I want to access each csv results using a[0] to a[1000] each sub-array looks like (200,4)
How can I solve the problem? I'm quite lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes, that is what `vstack` (and `append`) does. It merges things on the same axis (rows axis).

```py
a1=np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
# [[0,1,2,3,4],
#  [5,6,7,8,9]]
a2=np.arange(10,20).reshape(2,5)
# [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
#  [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
np.vstack((a1,a2))
# [[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
#  [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
#  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
#  [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

b1=np.arange(5)
b2=np.arange(5,10)
np.append(b1,b2)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If you expect (from those examples), to append along a new axis, then you need to add it, or to use more flexible `stack`.

```py
np.vstack(([a1],[a2]))
#array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
#       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9]],
#
#      [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
#       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]])
```

Or, in the case of 1d, use `vstack` instead of `append`

```py
np.vstack((b1,b2))
#array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
#       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

But more importantly, you shouldn't be doing this in the first place inside a loop. Each of those functions (`stack`, `vstack`, `append`) recreates a new array.

It would be probably more efficient to just append all your `np.array(preprocess(f))` and `b = np.array(app)` to a pure python list, and call `stack` and `vstack` only once you've read them all.

Or, even better, just append directly the `preprocess(f)` and the `app` inside python list. And call `np.array` only after the loop, and the whole thing.

So, something like

```py
la=[]
lb=[]
for f in csv_files:
    cnt +=1
    seperator = '_'
    app = os.path.basename(f).split(seperator, 1)[0]

    la.append(preprocess(f))
    lb.append(app)
a=np.array(la)
b=np.array(lb)
```

Comment: Thanks!! you really saved my time. I'm quite new to python and everything. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a new list (outside of the loop) and append each item to that new list after reading.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change from `vstack` to `stack`

```
la=[]
lb=[]
for f in csv_files:
    cnt +=1
    seperator = '_'
    app = os.path.basename(f).split(seperator, 1)[0]

    la.append(preprocess(f))
    lb.append(app)
a=np.stack(la, axis=0)
b=np.array(lb)
```

`vstack` can stack along rows only but `stack` function can stack along a new axis.

Comment: I am getting an error with your code. ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape

Comment: I should have given the full code. My mistake! I have updated the code. It should work now.